# Getting the current route from within custom directive in angular

Tags: angular, routes, directive

I am trying to implement a custom directive. I would like to get the current route in ngOnInit().. I have found some code like below.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appLeftMenuActive]'
})
export class LeftMenuDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input('appLeftMenuActive') pathKey;

  @HostBinding('class')
  elementClass; 

  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef,private route: Router) { 

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.events.subscribe((data:any) => {
      console.log(data.url)
    });
  }

}
```

**This code runs console.log three times** and i don't have any idea why. Any ideas? or a better way to get the currently active route from within this directive?

```
<a class="nav-link" [appLeftMenuActive]="'game'"  routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/game/list']">
```

Comment: this.route.url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console log is called multiple times because the router emits several events:

- GuardsCheckEnd
- GuardsCheckStart
- NavigationCancel
- NavigationEnd
- NavigationError
- NavigationStart
- ResolveEnd
- ResolveStart
- RoutesRecognized

You can trace how router works if you use options when setting up your routing:

```js
import {
  ExtraOptions,
  RouterModule,
  Routes
} from '@angular/router';

export const options: ExtraOptions = {
  enableTracing: true,
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([], options),
  ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

You can filter the output from events observable by event type, for example:

```
this.router.events
 .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
 .subscribe(...)
```

You can find more about router events:

- https://angular.io/api/router/RouterEvent
- https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events